# How to put quotes in powershell with variables inside python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, quotes, double-quotes

I'm trying to use paramiko to send to the server via ssh.
I can't get paramiko to send multiple ops in a row, so I made a powershell oneliner that works in ps:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "&Get-ADUser -Filter ('OfficePhone -like 888888') -Properties SID | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText Password! -Force -Verbose) -PAssThru | Unlock-ADAccount"
```

But I can't insert it as a string in python because quotes must be used everywhere in both python and powershell. Plus, I need to pass two variables to the powershell.
I tried like this:

```
commands = 'powershell "&Get-ADUser -Filter (\"OfficePhone -like f"{internal_number}"\") -Properties SID | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText f"{gen_password}" -Force -Verbose) -PAssThru | Unlock-ADAccount)\"'
```

To check, I also print the command
The result is this:

```
powershell "&Get-ADUser -Filter ("OfficePhone -like f"{internal_number}"") -Properties SID | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText f"{gen_password}" -Force -Verbose) -PAssThru | Unlock-ADAccount)"
```

If I understand correctly - the variable is not replaced (
How to correctly place quotes so that everything works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code, I've used f-strings **(formatted strings)** to insert the variables **internal_number** and **gen_password** into the *PowerShell command*. To escape the double quotes inside the *PowerShell command*, you need to use \". This way, the resulting commands string should contain the properly formatted *PowerShell command* that you can use in your paramiko **SSH** call.

```js
internal_number = "888888"
gen_password = "Password!"

commands = (
    f'powershell.exe -noprofile -command "&Get-ADUser -Filter (\\"OfficePhone -like {internal_number}\\") '
    f'-Properties SID | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString '
    f'-AsPlainText \\"{gen_password}\\" -Force -Verbose) -PAssThru | Unlock-ADAccount"'
)
print(commands)
```